# Return Redirect is creating 404 http errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

On our website after receiving successful payment response from payment gateway, we are redirecting the user to a thank you page. The line within controller action that redirects to the new page is:

```
return Redirect("~/ThankYou?refid=" + referenceNumber);
```

The controller setup is:

```
public class MessageController
{
    public ActionResult ThankYou(string refid = "")
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I have created a route map as:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ThankYou",
    url: "ThankYou",
    defaults: new { controller = "Message", action = "ThankYou", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new[] { "Portal.Web.Controllers" }
);
```

When I view the page by typing `website.com/ThankYou?refid=121212` on the browser it works fine but redirect from the controller is raising 404 http errors. How do I fix the errors?

Comment: probably it passes the default value, which is an empty string, thus, you get 404 error. Ensure the reference id is passed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to redirect like below. [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2)

```
return RedirectToAction("ThankYou","Message", new { 
   refid = referenceNumber  
});
```

`ThankYou` is your action, `Message` is your Controller and the third argument
your `parameter`

**Edit**

The above would form `http://website.com/message/thankyou?refid=121212`

In other to get a url like `http://website.com/thankyou?refid=121212`

You are to make `Thankyou` a controller and pass the above action into its `Index` action or make MessageController extend your DefaultController(initial startup controller), then call like below inside `Thankyou` action

```
return RedirectToAction("ThankYou", new { 
   refid = referenceNumber  
});
```

Comment: It will show the url as `website.com/message/thankyou?refid=121212`. I want to use a shorter url like `website.com/thankyou?refid=121212`

Comment: Then move `thankyou action` to your default controller (the controller of your startup page) and remove the second parameter ("message") or make message controller extend your default controller